# SQL0204N "DB2ADMIN.TA" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704

Tags: db2, table

There is a table called `ta` with schema `db2admin`.
When I ran `db2 select tabname,tabschema from syscat.tables wheretabname='ta' and tabschema='db2admin'`, it returned the row, which means the table was there.

However, when I ran the query `db2 select * From db2admin.ta` under the same user account, this error was raised:

> SQL0204N  "DB2ADMIN.TA" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

DB2 (as other standard-compliant SQL databases) converts unquoted identifiers to uppercase, so when you say `select * from db2admin.ta` DB2 will look for the table named `'TA'` in the schema `'DB2ADMIN'`. That's exactly what the error message tells you.

According to the `SYSCAT.TABLES` query results, you have created your table and schema with lowercase names. To access them you will need to quote both identifiers (separately):

```
select * from "db2admin"."ta"
```

Note the double quotes.